# Reorganizing Google Sheets data dynamically

Tags: google-sheets

I'm currently working with Google Sheets to import data from Contact Form 7 in Wordpress. All the data is coming over fine, but I wanted to see about formatting it in more user friendly fashion. I've simplified the example a bit, but the gist of the form I have created allows the user to request multiple versions of a graphic file with different wording as needed, up to 5(my example has just 2 for simplicity sake).

[image: Imported Data]

All the data is imported using the CF7 variables and ideally I wanted to clean this up a bit. What I had thought of as a solution was creating a second sheet that pulls in this data submitted in the first sheet into a more user friendly format, as I intended to use this as a work form for a designer to create the requested graphic once the data is received. With each request the name/department/email/date all stay the same, but I'd like to display the version and line 1 and 2 data on another line. Is it possible to reorganize data like this on the fly, so when a new form is submitted and adds data to sheet 1, sheet 2 would then update with the properly formatted info?

[image: Reformatted Imported Data]

Is this even possible to do? I did some looking online, but didn't anything that really related to this type of data manipulation.

**Solution:**
Here's what ended up working for my example

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({
Sheet1!A2:D,Sheet1!E2:G,ROW(Sheet1!A2:A);
IFERROR(LEN(Sheet1!A2:D)/0),Sheet1!H2:J,ROW(Sheet1!A2:A);
IFERROR(LEN(Sheet1!A2:D)/0),Sheet1!K2:M,ROW(Sheet1!A2:A);
IFERROR(LEN(Sheet1!A2:D)/0),Sheet1!N2:P,ROW(Sheet1!A2:A);
IFERROR(LEN(Sheet1!A2:D)/0),Sheet1!Q2:S,ROW(Sheet1!A2:A)
},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7 where Col5<>'' order by Col8",1))
```

Comment: @ritz At this point I don't even know if it's possible to do, so I haven't tried much of anything. Googling an answer hasn't netted me much, as it's kind of an weird, abstract question. I'm not a super user with Excel/Sheets so I don't even know where to start tackling this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

One way is to use arrays and the QUERY function.

For simplicity, let say that

- Columns A and B have the general information of the order
- Columns C and D have the data for version 1
- Columns E and F have the data for version 2
- Columns G and H have the data for version 3

On the output sheet, add the headers.
Below of them add a formula like the following:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({A2:B,C2:D,ROW(A2:A);IFERROR(LEN(A2:B)/0),E2:F,ROW(A2:A);IFERROR(LEN(A2:B)/0),G2:H,ROW(A2:A)},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col3<>'' order by Col5"))`

- References start on row 2 to skip the headers to avoid to include them on the output sheet.
- `ROW(A2:A)` is used to keep the order
- `IFERROR(LEN(A2:B)/0)` is a "trick" used to "hide" the order (general information) data for the second and following rows for the same order. On the select parameter of the QUERY function, it's referrey as Col5 on the order by clause.
- It's assumed that `lookup-choice-1` will never be empty.

NOTES:

1. If more columns were added, the column numbers should be updated accordingly
2. Don't use the `order by` clause to sort the result by the general information columns because the "trick" to hide the "labels". If you need to apply a sort, do it' before applying the above formula, you could do this by sorting the source range through the Data > Sort range... feature, so the data is sorted before  it's transformed by the above formula.

See also

- [Sort and filter your data](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en), an official help article describing Data > Sort range...

Comment: I have used this as a starting point and made some progress here, but I believe I'm having problems with the sorting by version, as I believe I need to sort by name of the person who submitted it. I think I'm pretty close, but the sorting is off

=ArrayFormula(QUERY({Sheet1!A:D,Sheet1!E:G,ROW(Sheet1!A:A);IFERROR(LEN(Sheet1!A:D)/0),Sheet1!H:J,ROW(Sheet1!A:A);IFERROR(LEN(Sheet1!A:D)/0),Sheet1!K:M,ROW(Sheet1!A:A);IFERROR(LEN(Sheet1!A:D)/0),Sheet1!N:P,ROW(Sheet1!A:A);IFERROR(LEN(Sheet1!A:D)/0),Sheet1!Q:S,ROW(Sheet1!A:A)},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7 where Col5<>'' order by Col5"))

Comment: Here's a link to the document if you'd like to take a look https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G07YS0GCUc9YprRifRJFlaJkSPepq8TcM1jJkpQpwMs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @jbwharris: The linked spreadsheet doesn't have the same formula that the one in your previous comment.

Comment: it's in A2 on Sheet2

Comment: @jbwharris: It's not the same formula. By taking a quick look, I was able to see that it ends with order by Col1 instead of order by Col5. Anyway I edited my answer to add some clarification notes.

Comment: Sorry, I was messing around with it to try and get it to work.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow that Data > Sort suggestion. Could I get some more detail on it?

Comment: @jbwharris: 1. Go the sheet with the source data, 2. Select the source data range, 3. On the Google Sheets menu bar, click on Data then on Sort range... 4. Set the sort options and click OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157837/discussion-between-jbwharris-and-ruben).